# INSERT INTO with WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, where-clause, mysql-error-1064

I'm running this SQL query:

```
$regSql = "INSERT INTO orderregel(AANTAL) VALUES('$aant') WHERE TAAK_ID='$TkID'";
```

I also tried this one:

```
$regSql = "INSERT INTO orderregel(AANTAL) VALUES('$aant') WHERE TAAK_ID=$TkID";
```

But it both gave this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE TAAK_ID='13'' at line 1

What might be the solution?

Comment: you cannot use where in `insert statement`

Comment: You would use the where statement in an update operation.

Answer (score 5):

`insert into` syntax doesn't have `where`

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

probably you wanted to use `insert into select`

```
INSERT INTO table
( column name(s))
SELECT column name(s) from table where condition
```

OR

```
IF ( condition )
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```